# Classes imported in servlet is not resolved in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, import

In my web project, I have a Class A, Class B (These classes is in some other project,but are being imported successfully)which is imported in CompServlet.java .
And There is a ListComp.jsp , which is importing CompServlet.java.
My problem is the ListComp.jsp is not able see class A and B. 
It's giving error A type is not resolved to a type.

Comment: What strange. A JSP is not supposed to import a servlet class, let alone contain any Java code. You're definitely going in the wrong direction. I suggest to improve your question and state the concrete functional requirement in detail. This way we can propose the right approach to achieve it instead of cluelessly dealing with an approach which doesn't make any sense. In the meanwhile, start at our servlets wiki page to see some proper basic kickoff examples of how a servlet and a JSP are supposed to interact with each other: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion. Certainly I will go through it. So what I am supposed to do when the Servlet returns response and While displaying I need class A and B type.Or while Displaying a form I need A type in select tag.

Answer (score 0):

Imports are not transitive. If class A imports class B, and class C imports class A, class C doesn't automatically import class B.

If you need to use the class B without typing its fully quelified name every time (com.foo.bar.B), then you need to import it. It's as simple as that.

That said, I concur with BalusC. Having Java code in JSPs is ugly, and should be avoided.

Comment: I resolved the issue by importing Class A , B in JSP. Regarding including java code inside JSP, For displaying a list of object property in the JSP , I needed the class import. So is there any other way of not using the java code and achieve the output.